# What is a propane burner with multiple torches called?

Tags: heating, safety

If you watch Mythbusters, you'll notice they have a propane burner with a bunch of nozzles at different angles.  What is this called?  I would like to make or purchase one for melting metal (in a crucible of course), such as Aluminum.

Comment: :-) I saw the title and I thought "I bet they watch Mythbusters!". I opened it up, and I was not disappointed. Glad someone was able to answer you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this is what you're looking for:
[http://www.amazon.com/Thunder-Group-Inc-IRBR003CL-Propane/dp/B0042QJNM4/ref=sr_1_29?ie=UTF8&qid=1304967864&sr=8-29](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B0042QJNM4)

Comment: Just be careful around the wine bottles. :-)

Comment: It was like a machine gun going off!!! :)